# Matrix.org Bot with UI/Cards and Clickable buttons

Tags: matrix, bots, chatbot

Tldr; Need to send messages into Matrix room, with message having UI and Clickable buttons.

First of, I am junior developer (1 month experience) working for an enterprise (xyz).

Matrix is one part of the big project. Basically, Company XYZ will generate some Json data, that I need to send in a Matrix room (with multiple users in room).

I have to make a readable UI/Card from that Json, and send it in room. This card will have some buttons that room users can click.

On user click, we get back an event about which button was clicked, and perform any corresponding action.

We are also making same thing for other chat apps like Teams and Slack. There, we have a bot for sending message. And Adaptive Cards for Teams UI and Block Kit for Slack UI. I am looking for something similar in Matrix.

I found [inline widget](https://github.com/matrix-org/matrix-doc/pull/2192) and [Room Widgets](https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/d/1uPF7XWY_dXTKVKV7jZQ2KmsI19wn9-kFRgQ1tFQP7wQ/mobilebasic) related to my requirement.

1.Has Inline Widgets been implemented yet?. Any documentation would help
2.Will Room Widgets work for my requirement?
3. Any other option, without using bot that can work for Matrix